# How to configure the rule set of SonarLint in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sonarqube, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I have installed sonar lint extension on my visual studio code editor and I was wondering if there is a way to enable or disable the rules which are used by the analyzer? There is a way to do it in Visual Studio and Eclipse but I couldn't find a way to enable or disable the rules on Visual Studio Code.

I do have SonarQube running on my local server where I can disable and enable the rules from the Admin UI page. If there is a way to configure the SonarLint with the server, that would be cool. But I am not sure how to do it. If anyone does, please point me in a right direction.

Comment: Have you tried pointing to your local server in the user settings of VS Code?

Comment: I tried, but there is no such property defined in the sonarlint settings. :/

Comment: GlobalSuppressions.cs doesn't work in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I don't think it does. But it's clear from the answer from core-developers on their group that this feature is being worked on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to use the connected mode which allows the user to configure (enable/disable) the rules on the SonarLint.

According to the discussion on the SonarLint Google Group.

> It's very likely that this feature will be added soon (within the
>   year), as we already started developing it for other flavors of
>   SonarLint (Eclipse).

This feature is currently in work in progress and can be tracked [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1277)

Comment: This feature works for user settings, but does *not* work for workspace settings.  This is very frustrating, because some rules might be appropriate for one repo, but not another.  Also, makes management of large teams difficult, as one would need to make sure that the user settings are the same for all users.

Answer (score 11):

Goto settings and search for `sonarlint`
[image]

Click on `Edit in settings.json`

Add to `"sonarlint.rules":` the rule you wand to disable as follow:

```
    "javascript:S1488": {
        "level": "off"
    }
```

the rule code is displayed in the floating box
[image]

Comment: Works in user settings, not in workspace settings. Thanks for the screenshot too. `  "sonarlint.rules": {
    "javascript:S125": {
      "level": "off"
    }
  }`